# Arithmetic operation in condition expression DynamoDb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update a nested field in map based on two other fields in that map and one value supplied by the client.

My code looks like this (or at least I want it to)

```
ConditionExpression: 'size(#ttid.#t) < (#ttid.#mq - :qw)'

ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#ttid': 'ticketTypeId',
    '#t': 'tickets',
    '#mq': 'maxQuantity'
}

ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':qw': quantityWanted // This is from the client
}
```

Where I am trying to update the map...

```
{
    'thisIsATicketTypeId': {
        'maxQuantity': 500,
        'tickets': {
            'thisIsATicketId': { ...thisIsATicket },
            'thisIsAnotherTicketId': { ...thisIsAnotherTicket },
            } // size(#ttid.#t) gives me the number of tickets on this map
        }
    }
}
```

Error message is:

```
"Invalid ConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: \\\"-\\\", near: \\\"#mq - :qw\\\
```

I know I could do an extra read and calculate mq - qw before the condition expression but that would cost me an additional read unit and it just seems... Stupid.

What can I do?